# htaccess regex question - 301 redirect spaces to dash

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm just wondering what htaccess mod rewrite regex would be able to redirect any url that contains a space, to the same URL but a dash in replace of the space.
For example

I'd want it to redirect any request going from

```
mysite.com/test/dl/1/the file name.html
```

to

```
mysite.com/test/dl/1/the-file-name.html
```

Is there any way you can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, IF:

1) you hard-code such rule (means, you know the file name in advance):

```
RewriteRule ^test/dl/1/the\sfile\sname\.html$ /test/dl/1/the-file-name.html [R=301,L]
```

2) you can use RewriteMap and external rewriting program (Perl/bash/etc script) -- see [Apache's manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg) for details (but I personally do not consider this as a very good option).

Otherwise you will have to do it yourself somehow (inside your own website script, for example).